# make git commit all files of specific type except for a couple

Tags: git, gitignore

How can I make git commit all files of one type, say `*.el` except for certain `.el` files that are specifically named.  So, I have the following, but the `*.el` seems to be overriding the `.el` files that I name specifically,

```
*
ignoreme.el
ignoremetoo.el

!.gitignore
!*.el
```

I have tried putting the files to ignore after the `*.el` as well, but no dice.

**EDIT** There are also many other files/directories that need to be ignored and that is the reason for `*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Each line in a gitignore file specifies a pattern. When deciding whether to ignore a path, git normally checks gitignore patterns from multiple sources, with the following order of precedence, from highest to lowest (within one level of precedence, **the last matching pattern decides the outcome**):](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html)

So put your wildcards up front and the exceptions later.

Answer (score 0):

If that's your .gitignore-file, try adding only the exact things you want to ignore, like so:

```
ignoreme.el
ignoremetoo.el
```

As far as I know, there is no reason to include a complete wildcard at the top (`*`) - if Git even recognizes that; why would you ignore everything by default?

Something like `git commit **.el -m "My commit message"` should work with my fixed `.gitignore` file.

*Update to comment:* The concept still applies. Add all the exact things you want to ignore, for instance like this:

```
*.abc
*.def
ignoreme.el
ignoremetoo.el
bin
```

When committig/adding now (`git add .`), all `.el` files will be added except those who are ignored.

So you can mix and match with wildcards and specific files. What you should not do, is ignore everything and then try to unignore certain things - that will probably just make everything very complex to manage. You could for instance check out [these gitignore-files](https://github.com/github/gitignore) to see what it's all about.

Comment: the point of `*` is your dont have to specify all the other types, its much easier in a case like this when i only want `.el` files out of an ever changing mix of types

Answer (score 0):

Won't git commit anything you don't have in .gitignore?  So your .gitignore should be:

```
ignoreme.el
ifnoremetoo.el
```

What it looks like you're doing is trying to not ignore all .el files (which as far as I know git does by default), then trying to ignore a couple specific files, when all you have to do is ignore specific files.

Know what I mean?